# How to animate a sprite based on its velocity?

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit

Hey I have this project in which the player is supposed to go up like Mega Jump and I want to animate the player so that when it goes left or right or down it changes its image according to it. Any ideas how I can achieve this? This is my code where I create the player.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate  {

let foregroundNode = SKNode()
let player = SKNode()

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -3.0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    foregroundNode = SKNode()
    addChild(foregroundNode)

    player = createPlayer()
    foregroundNode.addChild(player)
}

func createPlayer() -> SKNode {

    let playerNode = SKNode()
    playerNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: 80.0)
    var spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "IMAGE")
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture)
    playerNode.addChild(sprite)

    playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size.width / 2)
    playerNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    playerNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    playerNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    playerNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.Player
    playerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.Star | CollisionCategoryBitmask.Platform | CollisionCategoryBitmask.Monster
    return playerNode
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if player.physicsBody!.dynamic {
        return
    }
    tapToStartNode.removeFromParent()
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 30.0))

}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    var spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "IMAGE")
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture)
    if (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx < 0) && (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0) {

        sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "IMAGE LEFT")


    } else if (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx > 0) && (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0){

        sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "IMAGE RIGHT")

    }
```

I don't know if im on track or doing it all wrong, I am still learning sprite kit and swift. But if anyone could help me achieve this I would appreciate it! Thank you in advance

Comment: you should set up `physicsBody` on your `SKScene` object.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make sprite nodes directly with images if you plan to animate them. Instead, initialize a `SKTexture` with the name of an Image. Now, you can make your sprite node using that texture. From then on, just use textures since every sprite node has a `texture` property that you can directly set - `sprite.texture`.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in your update method:

```
Update()
{
    if(player.velocity.dx < 0 && sprite.texture != self.rightTexture)
          sprite.texture = self.rightTexture;
    else if(player.velocity.dx > 0 && sprite.texture != self.leftTexture)
          sprite.texture = self.leftTexture;
    //Add checks for down or up.  Order it based on what takes priority.

}
```

This code runs through every frame and updates your texture depending on its velocity.  Load the textures at the beginning and just reuse them to save memory and performance.

Comment: hey @meisenman thanks for that! I am trying to do it that way but I still can't manage to make it work. I updated my question with some added code, hopefully you can see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Player node has to by Dynamic.  Setting dynamic to yes will allow your player to take on the properties of gravity etc.  Setting dynamic to no is usually used for things that should not move based on physics, instead it is used for things that should stay in place or only move based on SKActions that explicitly set their movement behavior.  I am guessing that is causing your if(velocity > 0) checks to fail.  Log the velocity of your player to the console at the top of your update.

Comment: I set the player dynamic to true on my touchesBegan method to keep the player from falling down before the user taps to start the game.

Comment: 1.  I would like to confirm that you are using physics to move your character, not SKActions.

2. when changing the texture call: sprite = [SKSpritenode spritenodeWithTexture: self.rightTexture];  Maybe the property is being set but the draw() update isn't triggered.

Comment: I added my touchesBegan method so you could see that I am using physics to move the character, so if you tilt the device it goes left or right etc. But where should I set the rightTexture and leftTexture properties? I mean the images for each. I think that when changing the texture is not being recognised as the player's sprite. As I am calling it from the createPlayer() method